# Cannot Assign Value of type 'UIImage?' to type '[UIImage]' when generating a random image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to assign randomly a `UIImage` on my viewController from an array of images. However i always get the following error like on the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Because quote images are an array of images!

Comment: Please read this URL https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: And also what are you trying to do? Are you trying to access an image or adding an image ?

Comment: I am trying to generate a random image out of an array of images

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To get a random image from your QuoteImages array you have to first get a random value and then request that from your array

```
let randomValue = arc4random_uniform(10)+1
let randomImage = QuoteImages[randomValue]
```